# C# - How to toggle a button with commands

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to understand the MVVM pattern and so i started learning the concepts of binding and commands in C#. In order to understand this pattern i created a simple GUI for a proxy server. The GUI has two buttons, one for starting and one for stopping the server.

If a user starts the proxy by clicking on the start button i would like to disable the start button and enable the stop button. This way i can be sure that the stop proxy method can only be invoked when the proxy is running. When the user clicks on the stop proxy button i would like to enable the start proxy button again.

I order to realize this i created a viewmodel class that looks like this:

```
class ViewModelBase {
    public ICommand StartProxy { get; set; }
    public ICommand StopProxy { get; set; }
    public bool IsProxyRunning = false;

    public ViewModelBase() {
        StartProxy = new StartProxy(StartProxyMethod);
        StopProxy = new StopProxy(StopProxyMethod);
    }

    private void StartProxyMethod(object Parameter) {
        MessageBox.Show("Implement the start proxy method here");
        IsProxyRunning = true;
    }

    private void StopProxyMethod(object Parameter) {
        MessageBox.Show("Implement the stop proxy method here");
        IsProxyRunning = false;
    }
}
```

The code for the start and stop proxy commands is as following:

**StartProxy**

```
public class StartProxy : ICommand {
    Action<object> StartProxyMethod;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public StartProxy(Action<object> StartProxyMethod) {
        this.StartProxyMethod = StartProxyMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object Parameter) {
        //How to check if the proxy is not running (if so, this method can be executed)
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object Parameter) {
        StartProxyMethod(Parameter);
    }
}
```

**StopProxy**

```
public class StopProxy : ICommand {
    Action<object> StopProxyMethod;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public StopProxy(Action<object> StopProxyMethod) {
        this.StopProxyMethod = StopProxyMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object Parameter) {
        //How to check if the proxy is running (if so, this method can be executed)
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object Parameter) {
        StopProxyMethod(Parameter);
    }
}
```

Now im wondering how i can achieve this. I thought that i could pass the `IsProxyRunning` variable in the StartProxyMethod and the StopProxyMethod (in the viewmodel) and delegate the value of the variable to the buttons in the GUI. However this didn't work as expected.

I feel like i'm not looking in the right direction to archive my goal, if you have an idea where i'm wrong i would love to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [RelayCommand](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/) for the Command-Properties in the ViewModel.
In the CanExecute-Method return !IsProxyRunning or without ! for stop.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion pointed me in the right direction. However how can i toggle the button on runtime? In my viewmodelbase i define it as `StartProxy = new StartProxy(o => { StartProxyMethod(); }, o => true);` but when the proxy has started the button should be disabled (so `o => true` should become `o => false`)

Comment: in the viewmodelbase constructor you can use it´s Property IsProxyRunning, also in the funcs for canExecute.

Comment: I overlooked that part, thanks for your clarification. With your suggestion i managed to get it working and to get some understanding of the concepts. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you are doing it wrong.

You need to use this constructor for the `Command` (in the first part (`Action`) define the method that you execute, and in the `Func` define when the button can execute):

```
public Command (Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute);
```

Then you need to remove the StartProxy.cs and StopProxy.cs.

Finally, when the button is pressed you need to call:

```
StartProxy.ChangeCanExecute();
StopProxy.ChangeCanExecute();
```